# jQuery block UI causes scroll event in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-blockui

I am using [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element) and I am having issues with firefox as blocking an element fires scroll event on that element and in my case I have other actions bind to element scroll and mess up my app logic.

**Steps to Reproduce:** Firefox Only 50+

1. scroll div to end
2. Press block-ui button to block element
3. see console , div was scrolled
4. unblocking element also causes scroll event

**What I need :**
I want to avoid scroll event fired when element is blocked or unblocked.
This only happens with firefox. WHY ??

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/1nv6znLg/36/

```
// print on scroll
$('#scroll-div').on('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log('div scrolled');
});
//block
$('#btn-block').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#scroll-div').block({
    'message': 'loading ...'
  });
});
//unblock
$('#btn-unblock').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#scroll-div').unblock();
});
```

**Preview:**
[image]